# How to execute a select query on database using C# Firebird and display it in shell?

Tags: c#, sql, connection, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

I just started learning C# in Visual Studio and I got a task to do. I have to connect to a SQL database, execute a select query and display the results using Firebird. I have read through a lot of articles, but I got stuck since everyone is telling to do a different thing. Can somebody help me and explain how this works?

```
using System;
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static public void Main()
        {
            using (var con = new FbConnection("database=SECRET.FB;user=SYSDBA;password=masterkey;DataSource=sereverip;Port=3050"))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (var transaction = con.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    FbCommand result = new FbCommand("SELECT n.nrdokwew, n.datadok, k.nazwaskr FROM nagl n JOIN kontrah k on (n.id_kontrah = k.id_kontrah)");
                    result.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See links at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/firebird-.net-provider/info

Answer (score 1):

You're executing a query, so using `ExecuteNonQuery()` is the wrong method (that is for executing things like updates, deletes, DDL, etc). You need to use `ExecuteReader()`, and then iterate over the rows:

See [this example](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/NETProvider/blob/master/Provider/docs/ado-net.md):

> ```
> using (var connection = new FbConnection("database=localhost:demo.fdb;user=sysdba;password=masterkey"))
> {
>   connection.Open();
>   using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
>   {
>       using (var command = new FbCommand("select * from demo", connection, transaction))
>       {
>           using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
>           {
>               while (reader.Read())
>               {
>                   var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
>                   reader.GetValues(values);
>                   Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", values));
>               }
>           }
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```